Duplicate Key Error When Inserting Large CSV Data in Chunks Using Prisma CreateMany
I'm working on a job to insert records from a CSV file containing over 20k records. Before inserting, I filter the records to get a list of only the new companies that don't already exist in the database. Then, I insert these records in chunks.
Despite this, I’m still encountering a Duplicate Key error.
Here's the code snippet of the lambda function that saves records to the database:
const prisma = require("/opt/db.js");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { data, modelName } = event;

  // Map the model name to the corresponding Prisma model
  const modelMap = {
    company: prisma.company,
    lead: prisma.lead,
  };

  // Get the appropriate model from the map
  const model = modelMap[modelName];

  try {
    // Validation
    if (!data || !model || data.length === 0) {
      throw new Error("Missing data or invalid model name.");
    }
    await model.createMany({
      data,
    });

    console.log(`${data.length} ${modelName}(s) inserted successfully`);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: `${data.length} ${modelName}(s) inserted successfully.`,
      }),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // Log the error in detail
    console.error(`Failed to insert ${modelName}:`, error);

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: `Failed to insert ${modelName}`,
        error: error.message,
      }),
    };
  }
};


And here’s the code where I handle the insertion of new companies in chunks:
   const newCompanies = await getNewCompanies(companies);
    if (Array.isArray(newCompanies) && newCompanies.length > 0) {
      await processChunks(
        newCompanies,
        "company",
        "csv-lead-upload-lambda-dev-insertToDb"
      );
    }


Helper function
async function processChunks(items, modelName, lambdaName) {
  const BATCH_SIZE = parseInt(process.env.BATCH_SIZE, 10) || 25;

  if (items.length > 0) {
    const chunks = chunkArray(items, BATCH_SIZE);

    // Map each chunk to a lambdaInvoker call and await them all at once
    const promises = chunks.map((chunk) => {
      const payload = { data: chunk, modelName };

      return lambdaInvoker(lambdaName, payload);
    });

    try {
      // Await all invocations
      await Promise.all(promises);
      console.log(`${chunks.length} new ${modelName}s inserted successfully.`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error processing chunks:", error.message);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`No new ${modelName}s to insert.`);
  }
}



Could someone help me understand why duplicates might still be occurring, or suggest best practices to avoid this issue? Or what is the best approach to insert a large number of data?
